# Vector of generalized lambdas

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, c++14

Suppose we have a code like this:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> tasks;
```

And we add a task like this:

```
tasks.push_back([]()
{
    // ...
}
```

This works. But now we want add that task:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> v(new int(10));
tasks.push_back([v = std::move(v)]()
{
    // ...
}
```

And this code is not compiled.

For more clarity:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> v(new int(10));
std::function<void()> test = [v = std::move(v)]()
{
};
```

There are compile errors. Because the type of the lambda is not `std::function<void()>`.
But what is the type of?

Comment: A lambda has an "unmentionable" unique type generated by the compiler. Your problem is that `std::function` requires its function object to be `CopyConstructible`, and `unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

Comment: But in the example `lambda` is a rvalue reference, it calls moving constructor. Doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. `std::function` has a hard requirement that the function object used by `CopyConstructible`, and your lambda isn't because it captured a `unique_ptr`. End of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lambda is a `std::function`.  `std::function` is a type eraser -- it takes anything destroyable, copyable and invokable with the signature, and erases the rest of the type.

As your lambda cannot be copied, it cannot be stored in a `std::function`.

You can either make it copyable (by storing its state in a `std::shared_ptr` for example), or write a move-only `std::function`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

template<class Sig>class func;
namespace details{
  template<class Sig>struct inner;
  template<class R,class...Args>
  struct inner<R(Args...)>{
    virtual ~inner() {};
    virtual R invoke(Args&&...args) =0;
  };
  template<class F,class Sig>struct impl;
  template<class F,class R,class...Args>
  struct impl<F,R(Args...)>:inner<R(Args...)>{
    F f;
    template<class... Ts>
    impl(Ts&&...ts):f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...){}
    R invoke(Args&&...args)override{
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  };
}
template<class T>struct emplace_as{};
template<class R,class...Args>
class func<R(Args...)>{
  std::unique_ptr<details::inner<R(Args...)>> pImpl;
public:
  R operator()(Args...args){
    return pImpl->invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  explicit operator bool()const{return pImpl;}
  func(func&&)=default;
  template<class F,class...Ts,class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)),R>::value
  >::type>
  func(emplace_as<F>,Ts&&...ts):
    pImpl( new details::impl<F, R(Args...)>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...} )
  {}

  template<class F,class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)),R>::value
  >::type>
  func(F&&f):
    func(
      emplace_as<typename std::decay<F>::type>(),
      std::forward<F>(f)
    )
  {}
};
```

or [something like that](http://ideone.com/JNkVGM).

(Features needed to be added: rvalue reference to this overloads on `()`, maybe `swap`, maybe `assign` and `emplace`, maybe typedefs for `result_type` etc), maybe `target` and `target_type`)